# c# how i can copy multiple rows from datagrid through command

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I got little problem with my copy command. Im using it in datagrid through ctrl + c key shortcut.

This is my actual method for copy row.

```
 private void CopyRow(object obj)
    {
        var item = obj as System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid;
        var currentRow = item.SelectedIndex + 1;
        var cells = item.SelectedCells;

        if (_entityEnhancedNotifiedTruck != null)
        {
            Dictionary<ENotifiedTruckFlags, string> transf = new Dictionary<ENotifiedTruckFlags, string>();
            string value = "";

            foreach (var e in _entityEnhancedNotifiedTruck.EFlags)
            {
                switch (e)
                {
                    case ENotifiedTruckFlags.CheckRecordHasBreak:
                        value = "Řidič má nařízenou přestávku";
                        break;
                    case ENotifiedTruckFlags.CheckWeighingOn:
                        value = "Řežim kontrolního vážení";
                        break;
                    case ENotifiedTruckFlags.NoTaraWeighted:
                        value = "Chybí tárové vážení";
                        break;
                    case ENotifiedTruckFlags.SPZProblem:
                        value = "Proveďte kontrolu SPZ";
                        break;
                    case ENotifiedTruckFlags.TimeProblem:
                        value = "Proveďte kontrolu ložné plochy";
                        break;
                }
                transf.Add(e, value);
            }

            var myStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<ENotifiedTruckFlags, string> pair in transf)
            {
                myStringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}", pair.Value);
                myStringBuilder.Append("," + " ");
            }

            DateTime dt = _entityEnhancedNotifiedTruck.ECreationTime;
            var Date = dt.ToShortDateString();
            var Time = dt.ToLongTimeString();

            DeliveriesGroup delGroup = _loadingSiteService.GetTruckLoadingDetail(_entityEnhancedNotifiedTruck.RecordID, computerName);


            var clipboardText = currentRow + "\t" + Date + "\t" + Time + "\t" + _entityEnhancedNotifiedTruck.LicencePlate + "\t" +  _entityEnhancedNotifiedTruck.LicencePlateTrailer + "\t" + _entityEnhancedNotifiedTruck.DriverName + "\t" + _entityEnhancedNotifiedTruck.LoadingSite + "\t" + _entityEnhancedNotifiedTruck.State + "\t" + _entityEnhancedNotifiedTruck.ProcessTypeName + "\t" + value;
            Clipboard.SetText(clipboardText);

        }
    }
```

My problem is, this method can copy only one row from datagrid. Not all when user stretch mouse over multiple rows and click ctrl + c. Any tips how to solve this? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that your method is directly setting the Clipboard-text by calling `Clipboard.SetText(clipboardText);`.

You should rewrite it, so the method returns the builded clipboardText as `string`. Then you can call this method for each row the user has selected.

And after you've collected all clipboardText's from all rows you can do something like:

```
List<string> clipboardTextsFromAllRows = new List<string>();
// Call your method and save the return values in the list
string clipboardText = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, clipboardTextsFromAllRows);
Clipboard.SetText(clipboardText);
```

Comment: I suppose, in the list i can use new List<string>(){currentRow, etc and other strings} ?